# How to make translations with i18next on react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, crud, i18next

***I'm new to React, don't judge harshly, I haven't had to work with i18next yet. This is my Header.js file. And I want to make translation from english to french with i18next. When I press the button I want the language to switch from French to English and vice versa. But I want the language to change in all the files where I wrote the code. Continued below the code***

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "./style.module.css";
import Logo from "./photo/logo.svg";
import { TiSocialYoutube } from "react-icons/ti";
import { IoLogoWhatsapp } from "react-icons/io";
import { SiTelegram } from "react-icons/si";
import axios from "axios";
import { AiOutlineMenu, AiOutlineClose } from "react-icons/ai";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Header() {
  const [nav, setNav] = useState(false);
  const token = "mrfcaiL5UrlAu_zsWeADkwKKXFLxJK41";

   
  return (
    <div className={styled.header}>
      <div className={styled.header__container}>
        <div className={styled.header__info}>
          <div className={styled.header__media}>
            <IoLogoWhatsapp size={30} />
              <SiTelegram size={30} />
            

            <p className={styled.header__phone}>+996702521200</p>
          </div>

          <div className={styled.header__buttons}>
            <button
              className={styled.header__lang}
            >
              English
            </button>
            <button
              className={styled.header__lang}
            >
             French
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={styled.header__line}></div>

        <div className={styled.header__pages}>
          <div className={styled.header__logo}>
            <img src={Logo} className={styled.header__image} />
            <h1 className={styled.header__title}>Main</h1>
          </div>

          <div className={styled.header__chapters}>
            <ul
              className={
                nav
                  ? [styled.header__parts, styled.active].join(" ")
                  : [styled.header__parts]
              }
            >
              <Link to="/main" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                <li>Main</li>
              </Link>
              <Link to="/history" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                <li>About us</li>
              </Link>
              <Link to="/management" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                <li>Management</li>
              </Link>
              <Link to="/news" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                <li>News</li>
              </Link>

              <Link to="/contacts" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                <li>Contacts</li>
              </Link>

              <Link to="/vacancies" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                <li>Vacancies</li>
              </Link>

              

              <Link to="/services" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                <li>Services</li>
              </Link>
            </ul>
            <div onClick={() => setNav(!nav)} className={styled.mobile_btn}>
              {nav ? <AiOutlineClose size={30} /> : <AiOutlineMenu size={30} />}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

***File History.js. In the file History.js I do fetch api http://130.61.61.186:8055/items/History. With the help of get-request comes the text, which was written in the admin panel. And I want this text, which is written in English, to be translated into French after pressing the button. I want to implement this on all files of my react-app.***

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "./style.module.css";
import axios from "axios";

export default function History() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const token = "Fb79eACvxFjhn3afD7h7Akoi0MiofDFm";

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
        `http://130.61.61.186:8055/items/History`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          }
        );
        setData(response.data.data);
        console.log(response.data.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styled.container}>
        <h1 className={styled.title}>About us</h1>
        
        
          <div className={styled.text}>
            <p>{data.text}</p>
         
          </div>
         
    
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [article](https://locize.com/blog/react-i18next/) it shows how exactly you can implement the `i18next` in your project.

To summarize:

1. Create translation files (en.json, fr.json...) with key-value pairs.
2. Initialize i18next in i18n.js file with translation resources.
3. Wrap your app with I18nextProvider in index.js.
4. Use useTranslation hook in components to access translations.